# How many ways can $n$ people be seated in row s.t. person $ \beta $ is to the right of $ \alpha $?

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem**: In how many ways can $ n $ people be seated in a row if person $ \beta $  is to the right of $ \alpha $ ( *not necessarily adjacent* )?
**Answer**: We'll choose two places for $\beta$ and $\alpha $, there are $ {n \choose 2} $ choices for that ( there is no need to bring "order" between them since the moment their places have been determined, order is already established ). Afterwards, we'll place rest of the people, for that we have $ (n-2)! $ ways. So the total number of ways as asked in question is $ {n \choose 2} (n-2)!$

**My difficulty:**
Regarding $ {n \choose 2} $ ;  this means we have a set of length $ {n \choose 2} $ with elements that are sets of size 2 ( they are actually subsets of set $ INDICES $), denote this set as: $  INDICES_{alpha+beta} = \{ \{ 1,2 \}, \{3,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,4\},\{1,3\},... \} $.
But what does this set represent? the pairs of indexes where I can place $\alpha $ and $ \beta $ ? ( wouldn't it make more sense to have a set of lists of size 2? ).  And what about the constraint that $ \beta $ is to be seated to the right of $ \alpha$? how do we incorporate the sets $ PEOPLE $ , $ INDICES_{\alpha} $ , $INDICES_{\beta} $ into the solution process?

I understand the solution for the $ (n-2)! $ part, my difficulty lies with the $ {n \choose 2} $ part. Looking from the eyes of set theory, I denote $ INDICES_{ others }  $ as the set of indexes left for the other people after picking spots for $ \alpha  $ and $ \beta $, so using the multiplication rule we get:
$ G = INDICES_{alpha+beta} \times INDICES_{ others } $ ,
so $ |G| = |INDICES_{alpha+beta} \times INDICES_{ others } | = {n \choose 2} (n-2)! $

**In terms of sets, I created the following to assist me:**
$ PEOPLE = \{ P_1, P_2 ,... ,P_n \} $ = The set of $ n $ people , where $\alpha , \beta \in PEOPLE  .$
$ INDICES = \{ 1,2,3,...,n \} $ = set of $ n $ indexes which correspond to locations on the row.
G = set of arrangements of $ n $ people in row under the constraint of person $ \beta $  is to the right of $ \alpha $ ( not necessarily adjacent ) = $ \{ (P_1,\alpha,...,\beta,P_{n} ),(\alpha,P_5,P_3,...,\beta ),(\alpha,\beta,P_7,...,P_4 ),... \} $ where each list in set $ G $ is of length $ n $ .
$ INDICES_\alpha = $ the set of indexes for which $ \alpha $ can be placed.
$ INDICES_\beta =  $ the set of indexes for which $ \beta $ can be placed.

**Note**: there are intuitive ways to strike this problem, but I'm looking forward in applying set theory whenever I solve combinatorial problems, so If you can explain your answer using sets like above it'd be appreciated.

Comment: The $\binom{n}{2}$ part is choosing the two seats for the (unordered) pair $\alpha,\beta$.  It would be much easier to just note that for every configuration, either that or swapping $\alpha,\beta$ (but not both) would give you a configuration with $\beta$ to the right of $\alpha$, so $\frac12 n!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is $\frac{ n!}2$ since half of all the ways have $\beta$ to the right of $\alpha$ and half to the left.  This is the same as ${n \choose 2} (n-2)!$

In terms of ${n \choose 2} (n-2)!$, the ${n \choose 2}$ comes from choosing two distinct places for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and seating them the correct way round. Since you are going to do the ordering yourself, these two places  can be see as subsets of cardinality $2$ and you have to find how many there are.

An alternative would be to select ordered pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ with $\alpha < \beta$ (if that is what "to the right" means) so perhaps $\{\{\alpha\},\{\alpha, \beta\}\}$ such that  $\alpha < \beta$.  You still need to work out how many there are. Whether you say it is $\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$ or $1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)$ does not really matter: it still comes out at ${n \choose 2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Combinatorics is heavily dependent on analysis or arithmetic; using set theory is unlikely to help you avoid this.

Comment: Isn't $ (\alpha,\beta) = \{ \{ \alpha \},\{ \alpha, \beta \} \} $? . Also, this means that I'd have the set $ \{ (1,2),(4,7),(8,10),... \} $ [ set of all $ (\alpha,\beta),\alpha < \beta $ where $\alpha \leq n$ , $\beta \leq n$ and size of set is $ { n \choose 2 } $  ] representing $ { n \choose 2 } $ in the problem? And the subsets of size 2 I'm talking about are $ \{\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{\{4\},\{4,7\}\},\{\{\{8\},\{8,10\}\},... \}? $ ( which is the set of ordered pairs I wrote but all in set notation )

Comment: I should have written $\{\{\alpha\},\{\alpha, \beta\}\}$ and now have - thank you.  But my point is that the important part is  saying that there are ${n \choose 2}$ desirable pairs, no matter which of many equivalent forms are used to structure the question

Comment: I thought ${n \choose k}$ represents a set whose elements are subsets with cardinality k and not a set whose elements are lists of size k. So it's not entirely clear to me as to why ${n \choose 2}$ gives me a set of ordered pairs of size 2 and not a set of subsets of cardinality 2 ( subsets of set $INDICES=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$).

Comment: For example, why we have here $\{(1,2),(4,7),(8,10),...\}$ instead of $ \{\{1,2\},\{4,7\},\{8,10\},...\} $?. I know the first set makes sense but the definition of ${n \choose 2} $ tells me it should be the latter. Am I wrong in my understanding of $ {n \choose k}$?, does it actually represent set whose elements are lists of size k?

Comment: If $I_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ then considering $J_n=\{(a,b):a \in I_n,b \in I_n, a<b\}$ and $K_n=\{\{a,b\}:a \in I_n,b \in I_n, a\not=b\}$  there is a natural bijection $f:J_n \to K_n$ of $f((a,b)) = \{a,b\}$, so they have the same number of elements, namely ${n \choose 2}$.  So you can use $J_n$ or $K_n$ and get the same answer